# Add links between related chat sites at top, just like regular sites

Tags: feature-request, chat, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, navigation

Regular Stack Exchange sites have helpful links to the corresponding Meta site in the top navigation bar. Likewise, the meta site links mack to the corresponding main site. Further, you can browse to other SE sites by clicking on the "Stack**Exchange**" notifications widget at top-left.

Could similar links be added to the chat sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this already exists, unless I'm misunderstanding. If the room is affiliated with a particular site, it has the site's logo in the bottom-right corner -- that links back to the site itself. In the top-right corner is a "site rooms" button that links to a list of other rooms also affiliated with that site, and an "all rooms" button that just shows active rooms across the network